# Как отобразить период в диаграмме

Tags: typescript, angular

Всем привет, у меня тут одна задача имеется данные с датами и температурой одного. И у меня возникла проблема с датами, проблема в том, что не получается сделать от определенной даты до даты и обе вводится через инпуты и отображается на графике.

Данный код отвечает за этим, я могу одиночно сделать но не могу отобразить даты в lineChartLabels. А также эти данные должны отобразиться в lineChartData:

```
public StartDate(dateUser, endDate) {
    this.dateUser = dateUser;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    let a = this.percipateList.filter(m => new Date(m.t) >= new Date(dateUser) && new Date(m.t) <= new Date(endDate));
    console.log(a); // это дает мне промежуток
    this.lineChartLabels = [a.toLocaleString()]; // а тут я хочу вывести на график
    let value_1 = this.percipateList.find(res => res.t == dateUser);
    let value_2 = this.percipateList.find(res => res.t == endDate);
    let value_3 = this.temperatureList.find(res => res.t == dateUser);
    let value_4 = this.temperatureList.find(res => res.t == endDate);
    this.lineChartData = [{data: [this.description = value_1.v, this.description = value_2.v]},
    {data: [this.temperate = value_3.v, this.temperate = value_4.v]}];
}
```

Вот мой шаблон:

```
<input #startDate type="date" class="form-control"/>
<input #endDate  type="date" class="form-control" (keyup.enter)="StartDate(startDate.value, endDate.value)"/>
```

Comment: создай пример на stackblitz или codesandbox

Comment: @overthesanity вот пример [ссылка](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-z07q9) и на гитхабе [ссылка](https://github.com/eldoskadyrkul/city-weather)

Comment: ну репродакшн не работает - `core.ɵɵdefineInjectable is not a function` :) к сожалению не работал с `ng2-charts`, поэтому вряд ли смогу тебе помочь, в нативном `chart.js` (без обертки) легче все

Comment: @overthesanity мне просто нужно в label графики промежуток даты сделать, а там уже подходящие данные, касательно промежутка

Comment: @overthesanity теперь можешь посмотреть пример